# Compilation completes but shows as disabled?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having a weird issue with 1.9.x where after clicking enable / compile, I do get the message saying "The compilation has completed." + "Compiler include path is enabled.", however it still says

Compiler Status: Disabled

Compilation State: Compiled

Collected Files Count: 8134

Compiled Scopes Count: 4

Any ideas? Permissions should be fine as using suPHP with correct ownership

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by tweaking config.php in includes, replaced

```
//define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname   (__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

with

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname   (__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```